# Is there an offline image recognition app for iOS?

Tags: ios, offline, image-recognition

I want an iOS app that does offline image recognition. Preferably one that does it live with the camera.

Comment: What do you want to recognize? Language? Wine?...

Comment: @Bobby231 Objects, like how Wolfram Alpha can recognize objects in images. Words Lens already works great for words.

Comment: You can train &/or use a deep learning neural network to perform image recognition on a number of platforms including potentially iOS but storage space & processing power are likely to be major issues: - would you like an image recognition app that took an hour to recognise your image? - A quick search for pre-trained data sets show that it is not unusual for the data set to run to 400 GB or more - I suspect that your phone does not have the storage for that.

Comment: Steve, please add that info to the body of your answer. Please also add an example picture and the example output the tool should give. Thanks!

Comment: What should be the maximum size (megabytes) of the software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [Aipoly](http://aipoly.com/) does offline image recognition of basic objects. It is marketed for accessibility needs so I imagine if there are other apps like this one it might be easier to search for them by adding 'accessibility' to your search terms.